# Crashdump analyzing: CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter

Tags: c++, qt, crash-dumps, postmortem-debugging

I've got a crash minidump to analyze. My program is multithread Qt5 application. I'm not a debugging guru but usualy I can easily find place where program failed, but this time I can't. I opened dump file in Visual Studio 2010, clicked "Debug with native only" and it shows me where problem is: it is thread with location "__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter". Call stack is like this:

```
msvcr100.dll()!_abort()
msvcr100.dll()!terminate()
program.exe!__CxxUnhandledExceptionFilter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pPtrs)
KERNELBASE.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()
```

I expected to see stack with program functions and Qt internal functions. But this call stack tells me nothing interesting. So please tell me what is the "ExceptionFilter"-thread and how can I find place where program failed actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are viewing the application at the point where the unhandled exception has already been caught by the default exception filter.

That is, you are not seeing the line where the exception occurred.

Unfortunately, this means the minidump likely contains no useful information.

You might try inspecting the `_EXCEPTION_POINTERS` structs, it might contain the `EIP` of the instruction that triggered the unhandled exception.

See the value of `pPtrs->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress`, that should hold the `EIP`.

From MSDN:

> ExceptionAddress: The address where the exception occurred.

To get the stack trace at the point where the exception occured, read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313109.

Comment: Wow, you answered so fast, thanks :) Exception address points to kernelbase.dll, as I can see it is _RaiseException@16 function. Is it kernel fault?

Comment: @YuriM Lol, not very likely. You probably fed some incorrect arguments to a WinApi function, or code you called did it. Those functions will perform sanity checks and throw an exception if they don't like the data. Did you inspect the rest of the arguments? There might be a record of the call stack, in the structure.

Comment: I will do it later on the next week :)

Comment: I just found an article about how to get the stack trace - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313109

Comment: kb-313109 is the solution. It works perfectly, I managed to do what I wanted to do.